# How to enable antialiasing in JMonkeyEngine?

Tags: java, antialiasing, jmonkeyengine

I'm trying to enable antialiasing of objects, at least to some degree. It doesn't matter if it's MSAA or orthe technique. I just want to get some sort of antialiasing, since something is better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik you have a couple of options;

1. Set Samples to > 0 in AppSettings.

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
      settings.setSamples(4);
      MyGame app = new MyGame();
      app.setSettings(settings);
      app.start();
    }
   ```

Wiki: https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/docs/3.3/core/system/appsettings.html#properties

2. Add an FXAA post filter:

   ```
   fpp = new FilterPostProcessor(assetManager);
   fpp.addFilter(new FXAAFilter());
   viewPort.addProcessor(fpp);
   ```

Wiki: https://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/docs/3.3/sdk/filters.html

3. Enable anti-aliasing in the NVidia's application profiles. (Dependent on platform)
   https://www.nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/mergedProjects/nv3d/Tips_for_Setting_Antialiasing.htm

The FXAA filter is probably most expensive way to achieve it. If you can, go for option 1 and 3.